# How to apply animation to my header as the same as my body background?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to apply the same body animation to my header ?

Here the code below to my CSS :

```css
  /* =======================
BODY ANIMATION FOR LOGIN PAGE
=========================*/

#login-body {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
  height: 100vh;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}


/*=======================
  Header Section
========================*/

.header {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 111;
  /* background-color: var(--color-sub); original color background */
  background: rgb(252, 70, 107);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(252, 70, 107, 1) 0%, rgba(63, 94, 251, 1) 63%);
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
  animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

.header>.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__logo>img {
  height: 3.8rem;
}

.header__nav>ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  gap: 6.5rem;
}

.header__menuItem>a {
  color: var(--color-light);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: var(--test-h2);
}

.toggle-menu>span {
  display: none;
}

.header__nav input[type='checkbox'] {
  display: none;
}

.header__nav input[type='checkbox']:checked~.header__menu {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.project--thumbnail {
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .header__logo {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .toggle-menu {
    position: relative;
  }
```

I tried to apply for the header animation but it seems to not be working.
Do you why it won't apply my animation ? When I tried to change nothing seems to be changing ?
Could it be possible that the header cannot take the animation

Answer (score 0):

```
/*=======================
  Header Section
========================*/
.header {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 111;
  /* background-color: var(--color-sub); original color background */
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  animation: waveColors 16s ease infinite;

}


/* Animation Wave Color */

@-webkit-keyframes waveColors {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).